# Do something after sub foo in Perl?

Tags: perl

```
after foo => sub{
    ...
}
```

I just stumble upon code like above, which is called after `sub foo` finishes,

how does that work?

It seems it's not built-in feature of Perl,right?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's one of the [Moose method modifiers](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Moose-2.0202/lib/Moose/Manual/MethodModifiers.pod).

> Method modifiers can be used to add behavior to methods without modifying the definition of those methods.

Comment: @asker: no, it's part of the [Moose](http://search.cpan.org/~doy/Moose-2.0202/lib/Moose/Manual.pod) object system for Perl.

Comment: I just found that it's from `Mouse::Role`,not `Moose`

Comment: @asker: yes, it's in [Mouse](http://search.cpan.org/~gfuji/Mouse/lib/Mouse.pm) too. Mouse is a Moose compatible object system, designed to have a lower compile-time overhead.

Comment: Why do you call it a object system?

Comment: @asker: Moose and Mouse are a collection of CPAN modules that simplify the created of object-oriented Perl. The [Moose::Manual](http://search.cpan.org/dist/Moose/lib/Moose/Manual.pod) explains it better and in more detail than I can.

Answer (score 3):

Out of curiosity, I've tried to do it myself, and got code that works to some extent (no list context, no corner cases etc.).

Perl allows for horrible things.

```
% perl -wle 'use After; sub foo { $_[0] * 2}; 
    after foo => sub { print $_[0] }; foo(5); foo(6);'
10
12
```

Here's After.pm. Please don't **ever** use it.

```
use warnings;
use strict;

package After;

# make after() available after 'use After;'
use Exporter;
BEGIN {
    our @ISA = qw(Exporter);
    our @EXPORT = qw(after);
};

# prototype: bareword + sub
sub after (*&) {
    my ($name, $code) = @_;
    my $caller = caller; # get calling package

    # fetch old sub named "name" 
    # note $oldcode = *{...} is not ehough 
    my $oldcode;
    {
        no strict 'refs';
        $oldcode = \&{$caller."::".$name};
    };

    # defined new sub
    my $newcode = sub {
        my $ret = $oldcode->(@_);  # call old sub as is
        $code->($ret);             # call the after sub
        return $ret;               # ignore aftersub's ret val
    };

    # plant new sub into the calling package
    # avoid redefinition warnings 
    {
        no strict 'refs';
        no warnings 'redefine';
        *{$caller."::".$name} = $newcode;
    };
};

1;
```

Answer (score 3):

It is not a builtin feature as others have already stated. For programs that do not use [`Moose`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Moose), you can use [`Class::Method::Modifiers`](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Class%3a%3aMethod%3a%3aModifiers) to get these modifiers.

Comment: See also [Aspect](https://metacpan.org/module/Aspect) which can do similar wrapping of plain functions as well as methods.

Answer (score 1):

If `after` is a predeclared subroutine, it would mean that you call that sub, with `foo` and an anonymous sub as arguments. It does seem a bit odd, though.

`=>` is equivalent to a comma, so assuming `after` is a sub, it would mean this:

```
after('foo', sub { ... });
```

Comment: No, it's equivalent to `after('foo', sub { ... });`.